# Capture HTML error input validation when set in javascript (shows a warn) or check validation before

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I am trying validate a data to set in an input. I want to use HTML validation.

For example, I want to check if "aaaa" is a **valid data for an number input**. I wanted use `willValidate` or `validity` but I can not set an invalid value, the console shows (Chrome):

> The specified value "aaaa" is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+.\d+|.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?

I have tried catch the error **but it is not an Exception**. I retrieve the input value and it is empty after the error.

```js
var value = "aaaa";

try {
    document.getElementById("input").value = value; // Shows a warn
} catch(err) {
    console.log(err.message); // Nothing catching
}

console.log( document.getElementById("input").value ); // It is empty
```

**[See JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/SnakeDrak/qhz6xuf2/1/)**

I want to check if a value to set is valid in the input type. I thought set the invalid value in the input and check willValidate or validity but the browser shows a warn and the input value is empty. The problem is that my frontend set the inputs values via JavaScript but the user pass the values. When an error occurs I need show the error to the user and not put only and input empty.

I know that the warn is not an Exception. I want know shows the error when set an invalid input value in any type.

Comment: Essentially you want to test for a value-rejection, rather than an error? (I'm not sure there will be an event related to this, but I just wanted to clarify for my own understanding.)

Comment: I want to check if a value to setted is valid in the input type. I thought set the invalid value in the input and check `willValidate` or `validity` but the browser shows a warn and the input value is empty. The problem is that my frontend set the inputs values via javascript but the user pass the values. When an error occurs I need show the error to the user and not put only and input empty...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var value = "aaaa";
document.getElementById("input").value = value;
if (document.getElementById("input").value == null || document.getElementById("input").value == "") {
        alert("Invalid value");
}
```

Comment: Simple but correct. If anybody knows how get the warn error to show my user I will mark this answer.

Comment: I see. I don't know if there's a straight forward method of capturing the log, I think it's better to handle the validation & errors "manually"

Comment: @Holle ok this is correct but an example with checkValidity is not ??? For HTML5 validation???

Comment: True, but in this case the validity is checked automatically in HTML5 when we have type="number"

Comment: @Holle Yes as `required` does to elements that have null or no value when submited. This is not an answer for down-vote my friend since it answers the question OP posted.

Comment: @Peter Darmis I said that the value is not inserted via input... It is inserted via JavaScript and **I need check before set** so HTML5 Validation (checkValidity) or "required" is not a valid answer and doesn't work. My English is not good, sorry fot that. If my problem was "required" or "validity" I won't post on stackoverflow... I remove the down-vote for your help! Thanks.

Comment: @Holle Your answer is correct because you check the value before it is setted in the input. Peter Darmis suggests use HTML5 Validation or "required" attribute when it is not my problem and I explained it in my question. I know use HTML5 Validation and if not I will search in the W3 API/DOC. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It's because that's not an error but only a warning. You can check that in the console.

What you can do is check for `isNaN(value)`and throw an Error object.

```
try {
 if(isNaN(value)) 
    throw new Error("not a number");
 else
    document.getElementById("input").value = value;
} catch(err) {
    document.getElementById("error").innerText = err.message;
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8psz0y0z/1/) as example

Comment: It is not the answer. The input type number is an example, I need validate any input type. If the input is a date, the problem is the same. I need use the HTML5 Validation.

Comment: I think the point to be taken here is there must be an error, not a warning, to be caught by the exception handler.

Comment: I know that the warn is not an Exception. I want know shows the error when set an invalid input value in any type.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    function chkValidity(elemementID) {
        var inpObj = document.getElementById(elemementID);
        if (inpObj.checkValidity() == false) {
            inpObj.setCustomValidity("This is not a number or a valid number. And this is my custom validity message for the value "+inpObj.value+" which is being inserted via javascript. Determinig \"required\",\"min\",\"max\" and checkValidity it is enough to do the work.");
          document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = inpObj.validationMessage;
          alert(inpObj.validationMessage);
        } else {
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "This is valid number and within range";
        }
    }
    var value = "aaaa";
    document.getElementById("input").value = value;
    chkValidity("input");
    document.querySelector("#clickme").addEventListener("click", function(){
        chkValidity("input");
    });
```

```html
    <input type="number" id="input" required min="0" max="9999" step="1" />
    <button id="clickme"> Click Me
    </button>
    <div id="error">
    </div>
```

Comment: It is not an answer for my question.

Comment: @Pedro Gamez you wrote you won't to use HTML5 validation, then simply using the 'required' attribute checks for null or empty field. I think you are totally wrong and this answer should not be down-voted.

Comment: @Pedro Gamez you down-voted a perfectly correct answer.

Comment: I said that the value is not inserted via input... It is inserted via JavaScript and **I need check before set** so HTML5 Validation (checkValidity) or "required" is not a valid answer and doesn't work. My English is not good, sorry fot that. If my problem was "required" or "validity" I won't post on stackoverflow... I remove the down-vote for your help! Thanks.

Comment: @PedroGámez please run my example and read the message please. Additionally do check that var value is set via javascript. Bye and thanks a lot for a vote silly and quite unfair.

Comment: @PedroGámez you are telling me that the code snippet that you selected works but not this one of mine?? My friend might it be that you don't know how to adopt it to your script? Because it works just fine. Anyway.... Whatever you say mate... Glad i could be of help.

Comment: No, I tested your code snippet and not working. Enter a number and click on "Click Me". It shows an alert saying "is not a number" when It is a number... So yet I don't need this example, I said you, anyway your code snippet is not working.

Comment: @PedroGámez ok i just removed the initial text in my custom message. `checkValidity` will return false when not having a valid number (min,max,step,required determine that) and additionally it will not accept text inserted since the type number is used in `input`.  So basically it covers you in all aspects. If you still refuse to understand this i don't mind. But the code presented in one of the answers is part of what checkValidity does depending the input type and it's additional attributes that are passed.

Comment: I know how works checkValidity and I said in my question that checkValidity, validity, willValidate etc is not a solution for my answer so If you don't understand the reason It is not my problem, I tried it in my second comment. I want that you understand me but I am bad with English. If you understand Spanish I will explain it you without problems. Regards.

Comment: Based on the code you posted in your question @PedroGámez, the above answer is correct sir. If you can't adopt it to your script then there is no problem on that.

Comment: PeterDarmis please show me or shut up. Your code is not working. checkValidity is not working with javascript set. [Test it](https://jsfiddle.net/SnakeDrak/r2e89w5q), or [Test it here](https://jsfiddle.net/SnakeDrak/r2e89w5q/1/). I have tested multiples times to know if you has reason, but checkValidity is not working, in Chrome when set via javascript always returns true.

Comment: Of course, I don't want use "required". I want check if is valid simply. I know that with "required" checkValidity returns false **because detects empty input**, but how I said you It is not a solution for my question because **I want check a value to set in an input**. I want validate a value. Do you understand me?!

Comment: It is not difficult to understand. `checkValidity` cannot check the value because when you try set an invalid value in an input It fails and the input is empty...

Comment: @PedroGámez most probably i did not understand what you want to do best regards

Answer (score 0):

To check value being set by JavaScript, you can throw an Error, having `.message` set to warning displayed in the console, to catch if the input value does not match the same Regular Expression displayed in the console.

To check user input you can use `onkeydown` and `onpaste` events; use the `<label>` element to display message in your HTML, `onfocus` event to set the label's `.innerHTML` to empty string if the input value is empty an string.

Note, the message displayed in the console is also set at the input element's `computedName` property; though is not updated at user input and set to empty string following an `alert()` at the time of the catch.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      
      var input = document.getElementById("input");
      var label = document.querySelector("[for=input]");

      function handleInvalid(el, val, e) {
        console.log("value:", val, "computedName:", el.comptedName);
        var message = "The specified value <mark>" + val 
                      + "</mark> is not a valid number. "
                      + "The value must match to "
                      + "the following regular expression: "
                      + "<code style=background:#eee;padding:2px>"                          
                      + "-?(\d+|\d+\.\d+|\.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?</code>";
        // if `e` : `event` is not defined,
        // that is `val` : `"aaaa"` set at `try`;
        // not user input
        if (!e) {
          el.value = val;
          
        };

        if (!/-?(\d+|\d+\.\d+|\.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?/.test(val)) {
          if (!e) {
            // `throw` `Error` to `catch`
            throw new Error(message);
          } else {
            label.innerHTML = message;
          }
        } else {
          // if `val` is matches `RegExp`, 
          // set `label` `.innerHTML` to empty string            
          label.innerHTML = ""
        }
      }

      function handleInput(e) { 
        label.innerHTML = "";
        var text = e.clipboardData // handle `paste` event
                   ? e.clipboardData.getData("text/plain") 
                     // use `event.key` of `keydown` event
                     // if defined, else use `e.keyCode`
                   : e.key || String.fromCodePoint(e.keyCode);
        handleInvalid(this, text, e);
      }
      
      function reset() {
        // set `label` `.innerHTML` to empty string
        if (input.value.trim() === "") {
          label.innerHTML = "";
        }
      }

      input.onkeydown = input.onpaste = handleInput;
      input.onfocus = reset;

      try {
        var val = "aaaa";
        handleInvalid(input, val)
      } catch (e) {
        label.innerHTML = e.message;
        alert(input.computedName);
      }
      
    }
  </script>
  <style>
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <input type="number" id="input" />
    <label id="error" for="input"></label>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a Plnkr example: https://plnkr.co/edit/mLgCQfBmvZHb5cNGZWtN?p=preview